SSLHandshakeException while running Kafka server in docker container
Below is my docker compose for kafka container.
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: SSL_INTERNAL://kafka:9092, SSL_EXTERNAL://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: SSL_INTERNAL://kafka:9092, SSL_EXTERNAL://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: SSL_INTERNAL:SSL, SSL_EXTERNAL:SSL
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.broker1.keystore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS: broker1_keystore_creds
      KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS: broker1_sslkey_creds
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME: kafka.broker1.truststore.jks
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS: broker1_truststore_creds
      KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: " "
      KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH: required
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: SSL_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: true
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - ./secrets/:/etc/kafka/secrets

I am getting below error while running this.
Invalid value javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme for configuration A client SSLEngine created with the provided settings can't connect to a server SSLEngine created with those settings.

Followed some other links related to same but can't get pass the error.
Can't figure out setting for inter.broker.listener.name in Kafka with SSL
